# Form generic objects in method

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I am trying to make one of my function to be common for all my binding activities. i would like to hear some suggestions from you on this .

At present my code looks like :-

```
public static void stateDialog(Context context, String[] stateList, final FragmentSendAlertBinding binding) {
    mStateDialog = new Dialog(context);
    mStateDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mStateDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mStateDialog.show();
    mStateDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mStateDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_select_state);
    CardView cvState = (CardView) mStateDialog.findViewById(R.id.cv_state);
    final ListView states = (ListView) mStateDialog.findViewById(R.id.countryList);
    final TextView tvCancel = (TextView) mStateDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_cancel);
    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce);
    MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
    myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    cvState.startAnimation(myAnim);
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateList);
    states.setAdapter(itemList);
    states.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            binding.tvState.setText((String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position));
            mStateDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mStateDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Can i use something like :

```
public static void stateDialog(Context context, String[] stateList, final  ViewDataBinding<T> binding) {
       }
```

**stateDialog is an function created inside my Alert Class and i just want this function to be common for all my Binding activities .I do not want to create separate functions for my each binding activity**.

so that my this function can be used for all my binding activities not just for **FragmentSendAlertBinding**

This may seems silly to you but i just want to know that is there any way to achieve this .

Thanks&Regards
I have never created generic classes before , i just trying

Any help would be greatly Appreciated!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making it generic i will suggest you to create interface for that

```
interface StateDialogListener{
    public void onValueSelect(String value);
}
```

Your method will look

```
public static void stateDialog(Context context, String[] stateList, final StateDialogListener listener) {
    mStateDialog = new Dialog(context);
    mStateDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mStateDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mStateDialog.show();
    mStateDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mStateDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_select_state);
    CardView cvState = (CardView) mStateDialog.findViewById(R.id.cv_state);
    final ListView states = (ListView) mStateDialog.findViewById(R.id.countryList);
    final TextView tvCancel = (TextView) mStateDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_cancel);
    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce);
    MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
    myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    cvState.startAnimation(myAnim);
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stateList);
    states.setAdapter(itemList);
    states.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            listener.onValueSelect((String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position));
            //binding.tvState.setText((String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position));
            mStateDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mStateDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

And finally from wherever you are calling it

```
stateDialog(this,<your stateList>, new StateDialogListener(){
     @Override
     public void onValueSelect(String value){
         binding.tvState.setText(value);
     }
});
```

Comment: can i send binding object in interface method ?

Comment: I think you can send it, but i am not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent class for binding activity. Note that the class should have all the methods that you're going to use from the objects of its child classes. Then create other child classes that extends the parent binding class.

```
class ParentBinding{

    public void method1();

    public void method2();

    public void method3();

}
```

Cusom Binding class

```
class BindingClass1 extends ParentBinding{

@override
public void method1(){
  super();
}

@override
public void method1(){
  super();
}

@override
public void method1(){
  super();
}

}
```

Then your method can be written as

```
public static void stateDialog(Context context, String[] stateList, final ParentBinding binding) {
```

Comment: hello @Nawaraj , i think you didn't get my point , please read the question again.